Manipulating MS Excel ribbon interface externally
Having an standalone app (console, WPF, whatever) written in C# using Excel COM Interop.
This app may add menus via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.CommandBars and subscribing for callbacks (click handlers etc.) which is basically working ok.
However, this creates a new ribbon tab called Add-ins with menus much like the menus in old fashioned Excel (pre-Ribbon interface era).
Really I would like to manipulate the ribbon interface by adding ribbon elements more explicitly, e.g. adding a new ribbon group in the Home tab and add buttons etc. here.
Is this at all possible to do directly via the COM Interop from an external app?Hints please!
